# How to call javascript function on label OnLoad

Tags: asp.net

I want to call javascript function on label onload, reason I am using an enitity Datasource and assignng a value to this label, but I want to hide it if the value is empty.

Thanx

Comment: Can you try to give us a bit more information. What do you exactly mean by 'on label onload'. Are you talking about hte `Page.OnLoad` event?

Comment: How can I accept answer if its not what I want :(

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different solutions I can think of off the top of my head:

1) Bind an expression to the visible property of the label that returns true if the value is empty and false if it does not (this will hide it server-side)

```
<asp:Label id="yourLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("aField") %>' 
Visible='<%# IF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("aField",True,False))) %>' />
```

2) If you have jQuery then you can do the following in your script tags:

```
$(document).ready( function () { $find('label id').hide(); });
```

3) If you don't have jQuery then you could do some javascript like:

```
body.onload=function(){
   document.getElementById('<%=yourLabel.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
}
```

Warning: both pieces of javascript were freeform entry, so they may require some tweaking or spell correction to actually work

Comment: thanx Tarwn I am using Visible='<%# IF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("aField",True,False))) %>' /> but it throws error ' Invalid expression term 'if''

Comment: Are you using VB or C#? Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("aField",True,False)) or !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("aField",True,False)) might work better (sorry, the danger of writing code freehand without the IDE handy to correct me)

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" 
     runat="server" 
     Text="Name:" 
     Font-Bold="true" Visible='<%#   (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Server.HtmlDecode((string)Eval("Value")))) %>'>
</asp:Label>
```